# Creating a TGA using CGImageDestinationCreateWithData

Tags: c++, core-graphics, core-foundation, tga

I'm trying to save a TGA image. I've got the data as a `CGImageRef` and used `CFDataCreateMutable` to get the `CFMutableDataRef`, but I'm not sure what type argument with which to call `CGImageDestinationCreateWithData`. Looking at the UTType reference, these are the types which it says are supported by core graphics:

```
const CFStringRef kUTTypeImage;
const CFStringRef kUTTypeJPEG;
const CFStringRef kUTTypeJPEG2000;
const CFStringRef kUTTypeTIFF;
const CFStringRef kUTTypePICT;
const CFStringRef kUTTypeGIF;
const CFStringRef kUTTypePNG;
const CFStringRef kUTTypeQuickTimeImage;
const CFStringRef kUTTypeAppleICNS
const CFStringRef kUTTypeBMP;
const CFStringRef kUTTypeICO;
```

Would I use kUTTypeImage? If so, how would I let it know that I want to encode it as TGA? Should I put it into an intermediate format and then do the conversion myself?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that these UTIs can be created from a string. So, the code for the TGA UTI would be:

```
CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, "com.truevision.tga-image", kCFStringEncodingASCII);
```

...in place of `kUTTypeImage` etc

Comment: All UTIs are strings. You only need UTI-specific functions for comparison, among other things. Also, that function creates a string, not a UTI specifically (there is no “create UTI” function); since you have a constant string, you can create that CFString much more easily with the `CFSTR` macro.